# Define a class method in a module

Tags: ruby

I mean, I want to create a class method in my module that will be used by the class who includes the module. They are in separated files.

By far I have something like this:

```
module Base
  def self.all
    puts "All Users"
  end
end

class User
  include Base
end
```

But I'm getting: `NoMethodError: undefined method`all' for User:Class`

Can you please explain the problem and if what I'm doing is a bad practice or going against any principle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `extend` the module in your class, your code should be like this:

```
module Base
  def all
    puts "All Users"
  end
end

class User
  extend Base
end
```

When you do something like this:

```
module MyModule
  def self.module_method
    puts "module!"
  end
end
```

You're actually adding the method in the module itself, you could call the previous method like this:

```
MyModule.module_method
```

There is a way to just include the `module` and get the behaviour that you want, but I don't think this could be considered the "way to go". Look at the example:

```
module Base
  def self.included(klass)
    def klass.all
      puts "all users"
    end
  end
end

class User
  include Base
end
```

But like I said, if you can go with the `extend` class method, it is a better suit.

Answer (score 0):

Following Ricardo's answer, consider an idiom common among Ruby programmers - enclose your module's class methods into inner module, called ClassMethods(that's a mouthful, I know), and use and Module#included hook to extend base class with ClassMethods module.

More information here: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/